# ToolBarの背景の透過度を変更したい

Tags: android

Google+アプリのように、ToolBarの背景のみ透過度を変更したいのですが、それらしいメソッドが見当たりません。。。

ToolBarのsetAlpha()メソッドでアルファ値を変更すると、ToolBarの背景だけでなく、ナビゲーションやタイトルも一緒に透過されてしまいます。

[image: Google+アプリのToolBar]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Toolbarそのものではなく、背景のDrawableの透明度を変更すればよいのではないでしょうか。

```
Drawable d = toolbar.getBackground();
d.setAlpha(0); // 完全に透明
d.setAlpha(255); // 完全に不透明
```

Answer (score 1):

適当な回答で申し訳ありません。

http://www.androidpolice.com/2014/07/04/android-l-spotlight-colored-transparent-status-bars-give-apps-even-control-design/
の上の方の写真にしれっと
@color/transparentとあったのですがやりたいことってあってますか。

android:backgroundに設定するかsetBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT)で
呼び出したらいかがでしょう。

Comment: これはToolBarではなく、さらに上のステータスバーの色の変更方法ですね。。

Comment: ご指摘ありがとうございます

Answer (score 1):

こちらでどうでしょうか？
（手元のアプリでは透過されています）

```
ColorDrawable drawable = new ColorDrawable(color);
drawable.setAlpha(100);
getSupportActionBar().setBackgroundDrawable(drawable)
```